# Android app can not connect to localhost server

Tags: java, android, node.js, server

I've created `Database` in my localhost, and want parse data from it with android app.I Create server with `NodeJS` and it works i can see the Database in browser, but my android app can't connect with this localhost server.
Here is my Java code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 protected TextView tvData;

 public static ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
 private static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 private static ListView lv;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

   // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,   R.id.listView1, titleList);
   // lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    new JSONTask().execute("http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/people");

 }

 public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        int statusCode = 0;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect(); //connect to server

            statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();


            if (statusCode ==  200) {
                System.out.println("Server responded with code: " + statusCode);

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJSON = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("people");

                StringBuffer finalBufferdData = new StringBuffer();

                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject finalObj = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String peopleName = finalObj.getString("name");
                    Integer age = finalObj.getInt("age");
                    finalBufferdData.append(peopleName + "-->" + age + "\n");

                    Log.i("Hakob_log",peopleName + "-->" + age + "\n");
                }


                return finalBufferdData.toString(); //pases result to POstExecute
            }else{
                Log.i("Hakob_log","Error");
            }

        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(connection !=null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if(reader !=null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tvData.setText(result);
    }
}
}
```

I thnk something wrong with this line

```
new JSONTask().execute("http://localhost:3000/api/people");
```

Thanks

Comment: can u attached the log

Comment: Are you using emulator?

Comment: Did you can see you server from android browser or PC browser? Because on android device "localhost" will be resolved as your android device address, not your PC address. Also you need to be sure that your service is available from public network, and there is no firewall restritions

Comment: I'm testing on nexus 5 phone
yes i see my server in PC browser

Comment: which part of log i need to post?i havn't errors , thaere are warnings

Comment: I'm running my server on PC , not on android maybe that is the reason?

Comment: That's a reason, try to open your service url in android web browser and you will see that is unavailable. Try to open from some other PC and use IP address and I think you will see that is also unavailable. If so, you need to configure your service first. There is nothing with android code.

Comment: Yes You are right , and it is normally because my server is local, 
thanks for advices, I will try to do something wiht service
I've heard about Volley,maybe it will help me

Answer (score 0):

Use the IP-address of the computer that you are referring to as localhost instead, this should solve your problem e.g.:

```
new JSONTask().execute("http://10.0.0.100:3000/api/people");
```

Comment: I try it also but nothing is changed

Comment: Have you added the INTERNET permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file? 

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: What are the exception message that you are receiving?

Comment: I'm running my server on PC , not on android maybe that is the reason?

Comment: i don't get any exception message

Comment: Strange, try installing your app on a phone, it might be a problem with the emulator running on your PC.

Comment: I run it in android phone not in emulator

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. I think, maybe, the best solution for you is to have a look at Volley: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800

Comment: Thanks , i will see what is it :)